# Moving Console log information to browser web page

Tags: javascript

I'm a student working on a class project which, is a small video game. In the game I have a random number generator coded to a button between 1 and twenty. When I press that button the information goes to the console log. What I  would like to do is send that information to the webpage and have it stay there and act recorded.

```
Round 1: 5, 

Round 2: 16
```

So on and so forth. I don't want to ask my teacher for to much help because i have already asked him for so much. I would like to learn this on my own without getting direct help from my teacher. I've also looked all over the internet and didn't find anything helpful to what i'm trying to work on. 
Please help!

```
 <html>
 <head> 
<script src="js/createjs-2014.12.12.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var multiplier = 1;
var myStage, txt;
var score = 0
var buttonSheild;


function init(){
myStage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));

buttonSheild = new createjs.Bitmap("images/buttonSheild.png");
buttonSheild.scaleX = buttonSheild.scaleY = 0.25;
buttonSheild.x = 200;
buttonSheild.y = 0;
myStage.addChild(buttonSheild, txt);

txt = new createjs.Text("did it work");

buttonSheild.addEventListener("click", textClicked);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', drawNewFrame);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);
}
function textClicked(){
score++;
txt.text = "does this work?";}
function drawNewFrame(){
myStage.update(12);}


function demoRoll(num){

console.log("You rolled " + rollDie(num) + " out of " + num);

console.log("Multiplier = " + multiplier);

} 

function rollDie(num){

    switch (num) {

        case 20:

            var D20 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1);

            if (D20 == 20){

                multiplier = 2;

            }

            else{

                multiplier = 1;

            }

            return D20;

            break;

        case 6:

            var D6 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1)*multiplier;

            multiplier = 1;

            return D6;

            break;

    }        

    }




</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onClick="demoRoll(20)">Roll D20</button>
<button onClick="demoRoll(6)">Roll D6</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read about `innerHTML/textContent/appendChild`

Comment: Is expected result for text withing `console.log("You rolled " + rollDie(num) + " out of " + num);

console.log("Multiplier = " + multiplier);` to be appended to document body when `demoRoll` is called?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + textToBeInserted + "</p>");
```

Here's an example with your code:

```
<html>
 <head> 

</head>
<body>
<button onClick="demoRoll(20)">Roll D20</button>
<button onClick="demoRoll(6)">Roll D6</button>

<script src="js/createjs-2014.12.12.min.js"></script>   
<script>
var multiplier = 1;
var myStage, txt;
var score = 0
var buttonSheild;


function init(){
myStage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));

buttonSheild = new createjs.Bitmap("images/buttonSheild.png");
buttonSheild.scaleX = buttonSheild.scaleY = 0.25;
buttonSheild.x = 200;
buttonSheild.y = 0;
myStage.addChild(buttonSheild, txt);

txt = new createjs.Text("did it work");

buttonSheild.addEventListener("click", textClicked);

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', drawNewFrame);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);
}
function textClicked(){
score++;
txt.text = "does this work?";}
function drawNewFrame(){
myStage.update(12);}


function demoRoll(num){

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>You rolled " + rollDie(num) + " out of " + num + "</p>");

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>Multiplier = " + multiplier + "</p>");

} 

function rollDie(num){

    switch (num) {

        case 20:

            var D20 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1);

            if (D20 == 20){

                multiplier = 2;

            }

            else{

                multiplier = 1;

            }

            return D20;

            break;

        case 6:

            var D6 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*num)+1)*multiplier;

            multiplier = 1;

            return D6;

            break;

    }        

    }




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should `Html` be all capital letters?

Comment: @Cameron637 Console error says that it cannot read the property of insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: @Ryan hmm that's weird, it should work. Can you show me how you're implementing it?

Comment: +1 for [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: <script>
 var multiplier = 1;
 var myStage, txt;
 var score = 0
 var buttonSheild;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + textToBeInserted + "</p>);
Does this help @Cameron637 ?

Comment: @Ryan I just realized the issue. Your body isn't being created until after the script is ran, therefore it doesn't exist when insertAdjacentHTML is called, move script section to just before </body> tag and it should work

Comment: like so? 
</head>
 <body>
 <button onClick="demoRoll(20)">Roll D20</button>
 <button onClick="demoRoll(6)">Roll D6</button>
 document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<p>" + textToBeInserted + "</p>");
</body>
</html>
@Cameron637

Comment: @Ryan no like how you had it before but copy and paste the <script></script> tags and everything inbetween to just before the </body> tag, I will edit my answer to give an example